# My UIView do not respond on gestures after I pick that view using 3D Touch. _UIReplicantView and _UIReplicantContentView is not removed from `UIView`

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios9, 3dtouch

1. This is my cell. The `UIViews` in red rectangles are `UIButtons`:

[image]

2. Next thins is, that I bring my view to pick using **3D Touch** and back (**no pop**):

[image]

3. Now my buttons are disabled for touch. I cannot press any of them. It doesnt work. Only for cell that was picked. However I can once again pick new controller on that cell or... move it.

[image]

**Why my buttons in custom cell are disabled after I use 3d touch on that cell.**

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I register previewing:

```
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
            registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: cell)
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I did debug view hierarchy, before I use 3D Touch:

[image]

and **AFTER** 3D Touch:

[image]

> `_UIReplicantView` and `_UIReplicantContentView` is not removed, after I finish **3D Pick**, from `UIView` that I registered for previewing.

This is preview of `UIReplicantView`:

[image]